# Docker Compose deployment to Docker Swarm service name underscore issues

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

```
cat .env
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=docker-trino
DISCOVERY_URI=http://${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-trino-master:8080
HIVE_METASTORE_URI=thrift://${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-hive-metastore:9083

services:
  hive-metastore:
    build: 
      dockerfile: ../hive-metastore/Dockerfile
      context: ../hive-metastore
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/hive-metastore:3.1.3
    networks: 
      - trino-network-docker
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=mysql-hivemeta.rds.aws.com
      - PROJECT_NAME=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    ports:
      - "9083:9083"
    restart: unless-stopped
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"


trino-master:
    build: 
      dockerfile: ../trino/Dockerfile
      context: ../trino
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/trinodb/trino:latest 
    networks:
      - trino-network-docker
    volumes:
      - ../trino/master/conf/:/etc/trino/
      - ../trino/data:/data/trino/
     #- /.aws/:/root/.aws/
     #- /.aws/:/home/trino/.aws/
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      - PROJECT_NAME=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
      - DISCOVERY_URI=${DISCOVERY_URI}
      - HIVE_METASTORE_URI=${HIVE_METASTORE_URI}
      - INCLUDE_COORDINATOR=${INCLUDE_COORDINATOR}
    command: sh -c 'sed -i "/coordinator=/d" /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    echo coordinator=true >> /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    sed -i "/discovery.uri/d" /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    echo discovery.uri=${DISCOVERY_URI} >> /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    sed -i "/hive.metastore.uri/d" /etc/trino/catalog/hive.properties && 
                    echo hive.metastore.uri=${HIVE_METASTORE_URI} >> /etc/trino/catalog/hive.properties && 
                    sed -i "/node-scheduler.include-coordinator/d" /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    echo node-scheduler.include-coordinator=${INCLUDE_COORDINATOR} >> /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    sed -i "/discovery-server.enabled/d" /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    echo discovery-server.enabled=true >> /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    /usr/lib/trino/bin/run-trino'
    healthcheck:
      test: /usr/lib/trino/bin/health-check 
      interval: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
      timeout: 30s

    depends_on:
       - hive-metastore  
  trino-worker:
    build: 
      dockerfile: ../trino/Dockerfile
      context: ../trino
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/trinodb/trino:latest 
    networks:
      - trino-network-docker
    volumes:
      - ../trino/worker/conf/:/etc/trino/
      - ../trino/master/conf/catalog/:/etc/trino/catalog
      - ../trino/data:/data/trino/
     #- /.aws/:/root/.aws/
     #- /.aws/:/home/trino/.aws/
    ports:
      - "8081-8099:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      - PROJECT_NAME=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
      - DISCOVERY_URI=${DISCOVERY_URI}
      - HIVE_METASTORE_URI=${HIVE_METASTORE_URI}
      - INCLUDE_COORDINATOR=${INCLUDE_COORDINATOR}
    command: sh -c 'sed -i "/coordinator=/d" /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    echo coordinator=false >> /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    sed -i "/discovery.uri/d" /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    echo discovery.uri=${DISCOVERY_URI} >> /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    sed -i "/hive.metastore.uri/d" /etc/trino/catalog/hive.properties && 
                    echo hive.metastore.uri=${HIVE_METASTORE_URI} >> /etc/trino/catalog/hive.properties && 
                    sed -i "/node-scheduler.include-coordinator/d" /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    echo node-scheduler.include-coordinator=${INCLUDE_COORDINATOR} >> /etc/trino/config.properties && 
                    /usr/lib/trino/bin/run-trino'
    healthcheck:
      test: /usr/lib/trino/bin/health-check 
      interval: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
      timeout: 30s

    depends_on:
       - hive-metastore  
       - trino-master
networks:
  trino-network-docker:
    name: trino-network-docker
```

docker compose works fines but Docker Swarm service name has underscore which creates issue in other containers

docker stack deploy --compose-file swarm-compose.yml $COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME

```
docker service ls
ID             NAME                          MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                                 PORTS
rr677zgjqw3n   docker-trino_hive-metastore
```

Having underscore breaks other services so what can I do either replace underscore with hyphen

Trino container depends on name of Hive Metastore URL but having underscore in URL creates problem.

Comment: what is the problem with `_`s?

Comment: Use the service name as written in the file. Containers are automatically aliased with that service namé. swarm does VIP by default, so may want to change to DNSRR. Although it should not matter in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot replace the `_` to `-`, this how Docker Swarm (stack) works. The service name pattern in stack: `<stack_name>_<service_name>`.

There is open ticket for it in `docker/cli` project on GitHub: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/3364

As a workaround, you can use network aliases: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#aliases (If you create a network alias for your service then other service will find that based on the alias name)